# Embedding Videos - Various Questions

Tags: video, embedded-resource

I'm developing a website that will host some videos. The client wants control over the videos, so it will be hosted on the same server as the website. I need to know two things:

1. What is the best video format to use for this purpose? I.e. what is the best compromise between bandwidth and quality? And then, what is the best way to play this format on a website?
2. The client wants to host two versions of each video, hi-res and low-res. For the format recommended in the first part of this question, what would be a good file size per minute of video to achieve these resolutions?

Many thanks.

Comment: The best way to play it is with the HTML 5 "video" tag.  http://code.google.com/p/video4all/ can let you support older browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably flv format is one of the most used on the internet because it only requires flash ( which a lot of people have ) for the end user to watch the video, and for that you may use JW flv Media player
http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/
which is free also..

you may use a ( flv converter ) that will help you to define the low and hi res outputs
just google:
flv converter

Comment: thanks for the feedback Bassel.

Have gone with flash, but the client has decided on flowplayer instead, as they like the skin.